# MVC 5: ASPX and Razor View Engine in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am still learning and today I came to a point when I don't understand why something that should work, actually doesn't.

My sample project, I wanted to test both aspx and razor engine so i created razor view which works like a charm and now it turned out that there is no way for me to add ASPX View to my project and make it work:

(I want to make it work in MVC 5 not MVC 4)

1. There is no option for me to create strongly typed view using ASPX engine at all:

[image]

2. When I create it manually:

Add .aspx file to Views folder like this:

[image]

And put the code that would be generated if I was using MVC 4:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>>" %>
```

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial">

    <p>
        <% Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <% Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <% Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <% Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <% Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.Name) %>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) %> |
                    <% Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) %> |
                    <% Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and the View is accessed like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
        return View("List", employees.ToList());
    }
```

I am getting error, which means basically:

**TRANSLATION:**

*Server error in Application: '/MVCDemo'.

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Could not load type: 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage>'.
Source error:*

[image]

3. I tried as well to use this package from nuget, but to be honest I can't find any documentation about it.

[image]

=== ADDITIONAL INFO: ===

1. System.Web.MVC is present
2. Exactly the same application with Razor View works perfectly fine

I would be really grateful for your help guys.

=== SOLUTION IN CASE SOMEONE HAS SIMILAR PROBLEM ===

So, I managed figure it out, however there is still problem that Visual Studio for new projects support only razor. I wanted to try sth else, Spark for example. But it seems I cannot even import it anymore for MVC 5, I can do it only for MVC 4 project. And creating custom project template would require massive ammount of work I suppose to make it all work together.

Anyway, solution for curious ones:

1. I had to add this to my main web.config file, to system.web section

[image]

Alternatively add this, to my .aspx View (on the very beginning):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"%>
```

2. I had to add this, to my web.config file in 'Views' directory (to system.web section):

[image]

3. Finally in the ASPX View, I had to add ":", like this:

   [image]

And thank you all so much for quick replies, I really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Could you show the error message in English?

Comment: Also, have you tried making the "inherits" use a List rather than an IEnumerable?  Also make sure that you have tried "rebuild" and not just "build"

Comment: Not sure what the, I assume, error message in Polish is saying but double check that the page can resolve the Employee model class.

Comment: Translation added, yes I tried using list, I tried rebuild and deleting obj bin folders. Why I cannot add View in .aspx engine?

Comment: For what it's worth, MVC is compatible with Web Forms to allow you to migrate a Web Forms project to MVC incrementally, while still having the old website function as usual. The intent is not to allow you to just intermingle Web Forms and MVC forever and switch from one to the other at a whim. If you want Web Forms then go with Web Forms, but if you want an MVC project, then go full-hog with MVC.

Comment: Ok, so uhm, why in MVC 4 I could choose engine during View creation and now i can't? I could even import third party engine if I remember correctly.

Comment: Razor is the newer view engine that allows you to write less code that does more. It has been the standard since MVC 3. It is not very likely that anyone would want to create a new project with MVC 5 that uses the .aspx view engine, but there is still support there in case someone is migrating those pages from an older version of MVC.

Comment: So what about Spark View engine for example?