# ASPX View in MVC 5 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can we use aspx page in a ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. I don't need WebForm, I just need a ASPX page. I tried using "Add View" but it doesn't show any option to select ASPX Engine. I tried adding aspx page manually and tried to redirect but it never worked, it gives an error stating Resource not found. Can anyone help? I looked at other SO questions, particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550062/mvc-5-aspx-and-razor-view-engine-in-visual-studio-2013-update-4) one, but it didn't help. Or may be I didn't do properly, is there any blog/article/tutorial that explains how to achieve this?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696842/using-aspx-view-engine-with-mvc-5

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj that QA is from 2013. I cannot find any information regarding any updates to VS2013 that restore .aspx templates nor design-mode functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563811/changing-view-engine-after-project-has-been-created

Comment: Razor has been the standard since MVC 3.  Your statement "I don't need WebForm, I just need ASPX page" doesn't really make sense.  You might *prefer* to use the older syntax, but there is no use case which would *require* you to use the older technology on a new project.  That being said, if you select the 2012 Project type, you will get an MVC 4 project which supports switching view engines.

Answer (score 0):

- You just have to right click on the Views Folder ----> Add ---> View
  ---> Change the view engine on the same dialog.
- This will create a view with `.aspx` extension

[image: Add View]

***VS Version Details***

[image]

Comment: This is not available in Visual Studio 2013. Are you using the same version?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and my Add View dialog does not look like that. Mine looks like this: http://imgur.com/4YdD4F1

Comment: Yes, Even mine look same.